# How to transfer to woocommerce product id in jquery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

There is a script:

```
$(document).on('click', '.post-<?php the_ID(); ?> .add_to_cart_button', function(e) {
    $( ".post-<?php the_ID(); ?> .dobavlannovcart" ).show();

    var glavnikolvo = $(".post-<?php the_ID(); ?> .kuplukolvoinput .qty").val();
    var natovarkolvo = $(".post-<?php the_ID(); ?> .dobavlannovcart .qty").val();
    var res = parseInt(glavnikolvo) + parseInt(natovarkolvo);

    $('.post-<?php the_ID(); ?> .dobavlannovcart .qty').val(res); 
});
```

At the moment it is inserted directly in the php code, it is not correct. And when 2 identical pages, the script fulfills 2 times… How do I put the script in function.php or main.js so he continued to work as it should. To do this I understand I need to pass id in main.js or something to do in function.php.

Comment: you could use data to attach the id to the add to cart button dom element. and access the data by using `$(this).data('myId')`. Further reading here https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: You want product id to be displayed on some other div on add to cart button click?

Comment: @MujeebuRahman I want to count and display div display only on the item I added. Now you can look at allu.kz by Adding a product that on page two

Comment: @PrasunJajodia 
 
Could you show an example with my code please? I am not good in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the late reply.

In your main page where the button with the class `add_to_cart_button` is generated, you can edit the output such that your button is as follows.

```
<button class="add_to_cart_button" data-id="<?php get_the_id() ?>" ...... >
```

Now, 
in your JS file, do the following edit in your code.

```
 $(document).on('click', '.add_to_cart_button', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $( ".post-"+id+" .dobavlannovcart" ).show();
    var glavnikolvo = $(".post-"+id+" .kuplukolvoinput .qty").val();
    var natovarkolvo = $(".post-"+id+" .dobavlannovcart .qty").val();
    var res = parseInt(glavnikolvo) + parseInt(natovarkolvo);
    $('.post-"+id+" .dobavlannovcart .qty').val(res); 
});
```